# Click using automation id in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ui-automation, pywinauto

Please help !! I managed to install python 3.5.3 (32 bit) and pywinauto. I have started going through the getting started guide for pywinauto. I am using the inspect tool. I have launched the application using the code:

```
from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Trane\TRACE 3D Plus\TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe").
```

Now as I understood to tell python what the window is we use the:

```
dlg = app['TRACE™ 3D Plus']
```

In this screen I have value for automation id and class name using the inspect tool. Please tell me the syntax for clicking on that button using the automation id. For example, a button on my application has the automation id "Airflows" which is seen in the inspect tool. Now how can I click on this using pywinauto?

Comment: In this screen, I have value for automation id and class name using the inspect tool.  Please tell me the syntax for clicking on that button using the automation id. For example, a button on my application has the automation id "Airflows" which is seen in the inspect tool. Now how am I to click on this using python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automation id can be used with more detailed window specification (see [Window Specification](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#window-specification) chapter in the Getting Started Guide). In your case it should look so:

```
dlg = app['TRACE™ 3D Plus']
dlg.child_window(auto_id='Airflows').invoke() # or .click() that just calls an action
# or
dlg.child_window(auto_id='Airflows').click_input() # true click with moving cursor
```

Comment: I tried the code:from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Trane\TRACE 3D Plus\TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe")
dlg = app['TRACE™ 3D Plus']
app.Properties.print_control_identifiers().  It threw a lot of errors. All were showing the path D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\.... Errors were like pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError, Is there a way I can attach a screen shot in this comment ? It would be more clear

Comment: What is the real window title? Probably it's `'TRACE™ 3D Plus'` but you use `Properties` caption. Why?

Comment: In the document, it said, "app.Properties.print_control_identifiers()", But I also tried "app.TRACE™ 3D Plus.print_control_identifiers()" and when I ran this in the command prompt, I got the error, " app.TRACE\u2122 3D Plus.print_control_identifiers(), SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier". Could it be that the TM symbol is not recognised correctly ? Using the inspection tool on the main window, I got Name = TRACE™ 3D Plus and automation id = rootwindow . So what exactly should I use to print the control identifiers ? If possible, can I attach inspect screen so you can see ?

Comment: In the docs it's just an example (with another target application and another window title!). In you case it should be `app['TRACE™ 3D Plus'].print_control_identifiers()` or `dlg.print_control_identifiers()` as you defined `dlg` previously in the code. Please read all chapters of the Getting Started Guide carefully. It should explain the complete picture after all.

Comment: I understand the print control identifier in the getting started Vasily. But only if that works can I move ahead right ? I am not able to get the identifiers as yet, I made the code even simpler, first I just start the application using the start command and then try to print control identifiers like you said. So this is my code: .                                              from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Trane\TRACE 3D Plus\TRACE™ 3D Plus.exe")
app['TRACE™ 3D Plus'].print_control_identifiers().

Comment: When I just run this, I am getting so many errors in cmd prompt like 1) pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError 2)During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 3)raise MatchError(items = name_control_map.keys(), tofind = search_text)
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'TRACE\u2122 3D Plus' in 'dict_keys([])' So I am finding it difficult to progress further. I know this is simple otherwise, but I am really trying to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: You forgot to use `backend='uia'` when you calling `Application(backend='uia')`. WPF controls are not visible to default `backend='win32'`.

Comment: And make sure you use pywinauto 0.6.2 (just run `pip install --upgrade pywinauto`).

Comment: Vasily, sadly I have tried that too, it either says "    raise AppStartError(message)
pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process "TRACE\u2122 3
D Plus.exe"
Error returned by CreateProcess: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find th
e file specified.')"  or it says "    dlg = Desktop(backend="uia").TRACE\u2122 3D Plus 
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier". I have also ensure that I am running pywinauto 0.6.2. Could it be possible that TM symbol is causing the problem ? because it says invalid character in identifier ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139677/discussion-between-shivaram-panchagnula-and-vasily-ryabov).